# How to query mongo db lowercase in array using $all and $regex

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
dbo.collection("intent").find({ input: { $all : [ { $regex: new RegExp("^" + message.toLowerCase(), "i") } ] } }).toArray(function(err, result) {


      });
```

It showed eror

> MongoError: no $ expressions in $all,

Comment: Please provide sample data set, it will save a lot of time for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Without a sample dataset, or any indication of what you're trying to do, I can't really see why you'd ever want to perform a `$all` match over a set of regular expression.

If you want an item to match multiple regular expression, just write a proper regular expression accordingly and use `$regex`.

Something like:

```
{ <field>: { $regex: /(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)(?=.*word3)/, $options: '<options>' } }
```

Would return all objects of which `<field>` matches all three words.

You may also want to have a look to `$and` or `$or` operators that may help you too.